# Как исправить ошибку createContext с тайпскриптом?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

Делаю проект в котором хочу сделать аунтефикацию используя firebase, начал писать файл AuthContext но столкнулся с ошибками которые не выходит исправить. Насколько я понимаю то ошибка заключается в отсутствии типизации функции AuthContext

По задумке я создаю контекст таким образом:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();
//(alias) createContext<unknown>(defaultValue: unknown): React.Context<unknown> import createContext Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }) {
  return <AuthContext.Provider>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

export function UserAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

и потом я в своем App.tsx оборачиваю это все в AuthContextProvider:

```js
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

но естественно не получается ибо ошибка не исправлена.
Может кто-то обьяснит мне как типизировать createContext() и убрать ошибку: "(alias) createContext(defaultValue: unknown): React.Context
import createContext
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(377, 9): An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided."

Comment: `const AuthContext = createContext();` вы должны  передать [дефолтное](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createContext) значение.

Comment: Я пробовал задать дефолтное значение, например: const AuthContext = createContext(null); Далее в этом же файле в функции получаю ошибку: export function AuthContextProvider({ children }: any) {
  return <AuthContext.Provider>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
} // Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'

Comment: `<AuthContext.Provider>` тут вам нужно еще добавить пропс `value`, допустим `<AuthContext.Provider value={null}>`

Comment: таким образом получаю еще больше ошибок, сейчас скину кодпен, может вы увидите где ошибка...

Comment: https://codepen.io/IvaLu/pen/MWqjPOd?editors=0010

Comment: Сможете лучше перенести на [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io) ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143171/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-somebody).